# Greatest and least values on a sphere

Tags: calculus, geometry

Show that the greatest and least values of $xy − xz$ on the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =1$ are $±\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, and find the points where these values occur.

I'm not entirely sure what this question is asking

Comment: Are you familiar with max-min problems in 1-variable calculus? For example a problem like "Find the greatest and least values of $f(x)=x^2$ on the interval $-2 \le x \le +2$, and find the points where these values occur"?

Comment: Yes, I'm unsure how to proceed with three variables though

Comment: Okay, then the posted answer is what you want, although that means you have to know the Lagrange multiplier method, which is taught in multivariable calculus.

Comment: @S.Jane Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let use Lagrange's multipliers for $f(x,y,z)=xy-yz$ with the constraint $\phi(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$ that is

- $f_x=\lambda \phi_x$
- $f_y=\lambda \phi_y$
- $f_z=\lambda \phi_z$

As an alternative by spherical coordinates for $r=1$

- $x=\sin \phi \cos\theta$
- $y=\sin \phi \sin\theta$
- $z=\cos \phi$

such that the constraint is satisfied we need to find the extrema for $xy-yz$ that is

$$g(\phi,\theta)=\sin^2\phi\sin\theta\cos\theta-\sin\phi\cos\phi\sin\theta$$

for $\phi\in[0,\pi]$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.